# Fedora Silverblue toolbox container VSCode adding extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-toolbox

I have next Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora-toolbox:38-15

RUN rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc && sh -c 'echo -e "[code]\nname=Visual Studio Code\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo'

RUN dnf check-update \
    ; dnf install -y code openssl \
    && dnf clean all \
    && code --install-extension some-extensions
```

When I build it I get an error

You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument `--no-sandbox` and specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument.

What will be the best way to resolve this issue in a toolbox container?